# PHP MySQL connection sharing between objects

Tags: php, mysql, static, database-connection

I'm trying to work out the best was of having multiple objects in a program connect to a database.

I created an class with a static connection var. This seems to mean that only one connection is opened and all objects share it.

```
class Database {
    public static $mysql;
    function __construct() {
        if (!isset(self::$mysql)) {
            echo "Make static connection\n";
            self::$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "gamalert", "c45ualty", "events");
            if (self::$mysql->connect_errno) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->mysql->connect_errno . ") " . self::$mysql->connect_error;
            }
            echo self::$mysql->host_info . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

A normal object version. This creates a new connection for each object that uses it.

```
class Database {
    public $mysql;
    function __construct() {
        if (!isset($this->mysql)) {
            echo "Make connection\n";
            $this->mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "gamalert", "c45ualty", "events");
            if ($this->mysql->connect_errno) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->mysql->connect_errno . ") " . $this->mysql->connect_error;
            }
            echo $this->mysql->host_info . "\n";
        }
    }
```

I was wondering what the preferred option being? I plan on testing the performance difference later.

Comment: My preferred version is that you make an instance (the 2nd) instead of polluting the global namespace with static methods.

Comment: Have you also considered using [`singleton`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: @DanLee Where do you see him polluting the global namespace? He is just (somewhat) applying the singleton pattern here, nothing wrong with that. I'd prefer the 1st method, as MySQL connection reuse is better in my opinion, as the 2nd method produces more overhead in case of multiple queries/connections per request.

Comment: Yeah the global namespace was wrong. I mean I prefer dependency injection over singletons. And the overhead is no excuse for using anti-patterns.

Comment: I'm fairly new to the concept of patterns, have only found out about them while looking into this. However mostly while I've read the singletons are suggested for this, they are also considered bad.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to database is very expensive operation, and you should avoid creating multiple connections. So you should abandon your normal object version.

Option with static variable is better, but no ideal. You need to remember about copy this constructor in every class. And what, if you want to change something in this connection? Then you need to open all classes and changing it everywhere.

I think, you should create abstract object `Database` and extend it with your classes.

```
abstract class Database {
    protected static $mysql;
    function __construct() {
        if (!isset(self::$mysql)) {
            echo "Make static connection\n";
            self::$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "gamalert", "c45ualty", "events");
            if (self::$mysql->connect_errno) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->mysql->connect_errno . ") " . self::$mysql->connect_error;
            }
            echo self::$mysql->host_info . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And then creating new object, which will use this connection is simple:

```
class ExtDatabase extends Database {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Executing parent...";
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function hostInfo() {
        //no problem with using connection there
        echo self::$mysql->host_info . "\n";
    }
}
```

But... Its also not excelent option. Better will be using Singleton with connection, and abstract Database class.